# How to get User's likes, comments, and watched history using Youtube Api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api

I've been going over documentation and can't find a way to get user's latest comments. Going over activity feed only shows stuff like uploaded a video and made playlist.

Only thing related to comment i've found is that you can get comments for a specific video. But for comments made by on multitude videos there seems to be no way.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, we cannot access the information of those who liked the video, but we can reach the number of likes of the video.**

source : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs?hl=tr

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {
    key: API_KEY,
  },
});

//video info
const getVideo = async (videoId) => {
  try {
    const response = await instance.get("/videos", {
      params: {
        part: "snippet,statistics",
        id: videoId,
      },
    });
};

//channel info
const getChannel = async (channelId) => {
  const response = await instance.get("/channels", {
    params: {
      part: "snippet",
      id: channelId,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};

// comments
const getComments = async (videoId) => {
  const response = await instance.get("/comments", {
    params: {
      part: "snippet",
      id: videoId,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The activity list does return comments that the user has made (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list for details; specifically, look at the "type" parameter). However, there's not a way to trigger the response to *only* return comments, so any comment activities will be interspersed among other activities.

Comment: i made a comment on youtube video and it wasn't returned. Do comments activity has to be public? for it to be returned in activity list. Thanks for answering btw there is really no material on this

Comment: yup checked again returning stuff like uploaded video 3 months ago. Not that left comment today, yesterday and etc

Comment: Are you authenticated with oAuth2? I think you can only get comments for the authenticated user in the activity stream. If you are authenticated and still aren't seeing them there may be a bug.

Comment: yes i clicked auth with oauth2 by clicking and granting permission here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list#try-it